# is Alamofire compatible for iOS 11.0?

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am using this in my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MediaUploader' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MediaUploader
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'

end
```

if I read the documentation from Alamofire github in [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). it is said that the requirement for alamofire are

1. iOS 10.0+ / macOS 10.12+ / tvOS 10.0+ / watchOS 3.0+
2. Xcode 11+
3. Swift 5.1+

but when I set the deployment for iOS 11.0 like this

[image]

I have error like this

[image]

it seems the minimum requirements is for iOS 12.0. am I do something wrong? can I use Alamofire for iOS 11.0 ?

Comment: Does your pod file enforce a certain minimum iOS version?

Comment: @jnpdx I am not sure, but I have edited my question above, I have copy and paste all the script in my podfile now. really need your help to check the podfile :)

Comment: Uncommercial the line in your pod file that say to uncomment it to set a global version. Set that to 11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire 5 is perfectly compatible with iOS 11.

Cocoapods doesn't take into account your projects minimum deployment target. (apparently iOS 12 is the default)

You just need to uncomment this line in your `Podfile`:

```rb
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

set the correct minimum deployment version:

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

and run `pod install` again.